# Magento + Varnish/ReverseProxy + Apache + DirectAdmin causes NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID or ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: apache, magento, centos, varnish, directadmin

I'm trying to set up a Varnish Cache for Magento using reverse proxy (on Apache) to get https cached. I can't get it to work. So far I've got ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID while setting up reverse proxy (and 503 when trying to set up Varnish cache to respond directly on http/80).

Technology stack is as follows:

- Dedicated server (insane specs)
- Centos
- Apache
- Direct Admin (yeah, I know)
- Magento

My understanding of Varnish Cache is as follows:

1. HTTP: User->Varnish[:80]->Apache[:8080]
2. HTTPS: User->Apache[:443]->Varnish[:80]->Apache[:8080] (reverse proxy).

Magento settings are as follow:

```
web/seo/use_rewrites - 1
web/unsecure/base_url - https://www.{domain}.com/  //Previously it didn't work when I set this up with http. That's why it's https. Tested with http and no difference now.
web/unsecure/base_link_url - {{unsecure_base_url}}
web/unsecure/base_static_url -
web/unsecure/base_media_url -
web/secure/base_url - https://www.{domain}.com/
web/secure/use_in_frontend - 1  //tested 0, no difference
web/secure/use_in_adminhtml - 1 //tested 0, no difference
web/secure/base_link_url - {{secure_base_url}}
web/secure/base_static_url -
web/secure/base_media_url -
web/secure/offloader_header - SSL_OFFLOADED
web/url/use_store - 0
web/url/redirect_to_base - 1 //tested 0, infinite loading
web/default/front - cms
web/default/cms_home_page - home
web/default/no_route - cms/noroute/index
web/default/cms_no_route - no-route
web/default/cms_no_cookies - enable-cookies
web/default/show_cms_breadcrumbs - 1
web/cookie/cookie_lifetime - 3600
web/cookie/cookie_path -
web/cookie/cookie_domain -
web/cookie/cookie_httponly - 0
web/cookie/cookie_restriction - 0
web/session/use_remote_addr - 0
web/session/use_http_via - 0
web/session/use_http_x_forwarded_for - 0
web/session/use_http_user_agent - 0
web/session/use_frontend_sid - 1
web/browser_capabilities/cookies - 1
web/browser_capabilities/javascript - 1
web/browser_capabilities/local_storage - 0
web/default_layouts/default_product_layout -
web/default_layouts/default_category_layout -
web/default_layouts/default_cms_layout - 1column
```

httpd.conf:

```
    ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
    Listen 8080
    <IfModule unixd_module>
    User apache
    Group apache
    </IfModule>
    LoadModule php7_module        /usr/lib/apache/libphp7.so
    Include /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-phpmodules.conf
    DocumentRoot "/home/admin/domains/{domain}.com/public_html"
    <IfModule dir_module>
        Include /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-directoryindex.conf
    </IfModule>
    <Files ".ht*">
        Require all denied
    </Files>
    <Files ".user.ini">
        Require all denied
    </Files>
    LogLevel warn

    <IfModule log_config_module>
        #replace %b with %O for more accurate logging
        <IfModule mod_logio.c>
          LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
          LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
          LogFormat "%O %I" bytes

          LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
        </IfModule>

        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log common
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule alias_module>
        # Include some DirectAdmin alias
        Include conf/extra/httpd-alias.conf
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mime_module>
        TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AddHandler type-map var
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
        AddType video/x-ms-asf .avi
        AddType video/mpeg .mpg
        AddType video/mpeg .mpeg
        AddType video/quicktime .mov
        AddType video/x-ms-wmv .wmv
    </IfModule>

    incldes x20
    Include conf/extra/directadmin-vhosts.conf
    <IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    </IfModule>


!!!-----------------------------And here comes DirectAdmin httpd.conf:----------------------------!!!



[root@  ~]# cat /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/httpd.conf
<Directory "/home/admin/public_html">
        <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
                RMode config
                RUidGid admin admin
                #RGroups apache access
                RGroups @none
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
                SuexecUserGroup admin admin
        </IfModule>
                php_admin_flag engine ON
                php_admin_value sendmail_path '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f admin@{domain}.com'
                php_admin_value mail.log /home/admin/.php/php-mail.log
                php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear/:/dev/urandom:/usr/local/lib/php/:/usr/local/php72/lib/php/
</Directory>

<VirtualHost {ip}:8080 >
        ServerName www.{domain}.com
#        ServerAlias www.{domain}.com {domain}.com //tested "on" - see errors
        ServerAdmin webmaster@{domain}.com
        DocumentRoot /home/admin/domains/{domain}.com/public_html
#        UseCanonicalName OFF //tested uncommenting - see errors
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
                SuexecUserGroup admin admin
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
                RMode config
                RUidGid admin admin
                #RGroups apache access
                RGroups @none
        </IfModule>
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/{domain}.com.bytes bytes
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/{domain}.com.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/{domain}.com.error.log
        <Directory /home/admin/domains/{domain}.com/public_html>
                AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=Indexes,IncludesNOEXEC,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch,FollowSymLinks,None
                Options -ExecCGI -Includes +IncludesNOEXEC
                php_admin_flag engine ON
                php_admin_value sendmail_path '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f admin@{domain}.com'
                php_admin_value mail.log /home/admin/.php/php-mail.log
                php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear/:/dev/urandom:/usr/local/lib/php/:/usr/local/php72/lib/php/
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost {ip}:443 >
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/{domain}.com.cert.combined
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/{domain}.com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/admin/domains/{domain}.com.cacert
        ServerName www.{domain}.com


    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:80/

    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

        ServerAlias www.{domain}.com {domain}.com
#       ServerAdmin webmaster@{domain}.com
        DocumentRoot /home/admin/domains/{domain}.com/private_html
#       UseCanonicalName OFF
#       <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
#               SuexecUserGroup admin admin
#       </IfModule>
#       <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
#               RMode config
#               RUidGid admin admin
#               #RGroups apache access
#               RGroups @none
#       </IfModule>
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/{domain}.com.bytes bytes
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/{domain}.com.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/{domain}.com.error.log
#       <Directory /home/admin/domains/{domain}.com/private_html>
#               AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=Indexes,IncludesNOEXEC,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch,FollowSymLinks,None
#               Options -ExecCGI -Includes +IncludesNOEXEC
#               php_admin_flag engine ON
#               php_admin_value sendmail_path '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f admin@{domain}.com'
#               php_admin_value mail.log /home/admin/.php/php-mail.log
#               php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear/:/dev/urandom:/usr/local/lib/php/:/usr/local/php72/lib/php/
#       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

PLEASE NOTE: I just want to get this to work, I will transfer all the changes to a seperate file that will not get overwritten by DA.

netstat:

```
[root@  ~]# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3037/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2203/exim
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2208/dovecot
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19248/varnishd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2208/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2203/exim
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2208/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2208/dovecot
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd
***tcp     0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19248/varnishd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2203/exim
tcp        0      0 {ip}:53                 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3037/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3037/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2226/pure-ftpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2201/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      3037/named
***tcp6    0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      19143/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      2860/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::2222                 :::*                    LISTEN      19694/directadmin
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd
***tcp6    0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      19248/varnishd
***tcp6    0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      19143/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      3037/named
tcp6       0      0 :::21                   :::*                    LISTEN      2226/pure-ftpd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2201/sshd
udp        0      0 {ip}:53                 0.0.0.0:*                           3037/named
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           3037/named
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           1/systemd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           1341/chronyd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:659             0.0.0.0:*                           1356/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                3037/named
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                1/systemd
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                1341/chronyd
udp6       0      0 :::659                  :::*                                1356/rpcbind
```

Now the problems (with above settings):

- https://{domain}.com/ causes NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
- https://www.{domain}.com/ causes ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
- https://{domain}.com/test.php causes NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
- https://www.{domain}.com/test.php works fine (tho not served by Varnish)

with server alias on:

- https://{domain}.com/ infinite loading
- https://www.{domain}.com/ infinite loading
- https://{domain}.com/test.php works fine (tho not served by Varnish)
- https://www.{domain}.com/test.php works fine (tho not served by Varnish)

I don't think it makes sense to paste every single combination of settings and errors thus I would like to ask you if you can see where the problem might be (other than the use of DA).

Since I think that it is before it gets to varnish.params and varnish.vcl I didn't paste those files. I somewhat suspect .htaccess but you will tell me what other files I should paste.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you do set `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"` in your Apache configuration in the port 443 vhost.

This should announce to your backend that although the connection is done in *plain HTTP*, it was originally terminated as an *HTTPS* connection.

Currently your Magento configuration uses `SSL_OFFLOADED` as the ofloading header, however your Apache config uses `X-Forwarded-Proto`.

Can you try updating your Magento config as follows?

`web/secure/offloader_header - X-FORWARDED-PROTO`

This should help Magento look for the right header and realize it doesn't need to redirect back to HTTPS, since the page was already terminated as HTTPS.